# Stale Element Reference Exception on Get Text command

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am getting a Stale Element exception on a Get Text command.

Here is the code:

```
Get Text
[Arguments] ${locator}
Wait For Condition return document.readyState=="complete"
Wait Until Page Contains Element ${locator}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds 30 30 Identify Element ${locator}
Wait Until Element Is Visible ${locator}
Sleep 2s
${text} SeleniumLibrary.Get Text ${locator}
[Return] ${text}
```

Then further down, this function is passed to populate a spreadsheet:

```
${Received Amount}= Get Text (//*[@id="fxConfirmModalHeaderFx"]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[14]/span/span[1]) | (//*[@id="fxConfirmModalHeaderFx"]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/div[14]/span/span[1])
Log to console Received Amount:${Received Amount}
```

Here is the xpath to find the field:

`(//*[@id="fxConfirmModalHeaderFx"]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[14]/span/span[1]) | (//*[@id="fxConfirmModalHeaderFx"]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/div[14]/span/span[1])`

And the HTML of the element on the page:

```
<div _ngcontent-pfc-c193="" class="A12 reAmtDetail"><span _ngcontent-pfc-c193=""><span class="sr-only">700.00 US dollars</span><span aria-hidden="true">$700.00</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="currency-inline"> USD</span></span></div>
```

Here is the error:
`StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.225)`

I did try a try catch but when I do that, then no data gets passed, all the fields are blank.

Here is the code for that:

```
Get Text2 
[Arguments] ${locator}
Wait For Condition return document.readyState=="complete"
Wait Until Page Contains Element ${locator}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds 5 5 Identify Element ${locator}
Wait Until Element Is Visible ${locator}
Sleep 2s
${text}= Set Variable ${EMPTY}
:FOR ${INDEX} IN RANGE 3
\ Run Keyword And Ignore Error ${text}= SeleniumLibrary.Get Text ${locator}
\ Exit For Loop If '${text}' != '${EMPTY}' # Break the loop if text is retrieved
\ Sleep 2s # Wait before retrying
[Return] ${text}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add **Reload Page** as a keyword before you do Get Text for an element.